# How to run couchdb and superlogin on the same port?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, couchdb, port

I am using a Couchdb 2.0 database on a server, and run superlogin in a separate Node.js server process on the same machine & IP address.

- Couchdb is on port 5984
- Superlogin is on port 3000

I would like users to be able to connect from anywhere, however some companies are blocking most ports except the HTTP port 80, which prevents the users working in these companies to access the database.

So I would like to have both the Couchdb and the superlogin process listen the same port, number 80.

Do you have any idea of how to do that (I can easily change the configuration of each to listen the port 80, but this will obviously cause a conflict if I do nothing else). I believe I would hook the Couchdb server to make it call the superlogin javascript code but don't know how to do this / if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Only one application can be listening for connections on any one port.

You'll need a third service (e.g. httpd, nginx) to listen on port 80 and proxy requests to the appropriate port.

The routing can be be done in many ways, including by virtual host and path prefix.

Comment: Many thanks, I have tried this but can't make it work, more details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987366/apache2-to-dispatch-requests-to-couchdb-2-0-and-superlogin-all-on-same-ip-with